# Android Studio Can't Create new Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the most recent Android Studio and today my Mac crashed.  After rebooting, I opened Android Studio and now all of my projects are erroring out with the Android URI not being found.  They won't build, won't make, nothing.  If I create a new Project, Android project is not one of my options, just all the rest of the options.
Is there anything I can do besides remove and reinstall?

Comment: Can you show us some specific screenshots/quotes of the errors, etc.?

Comment: Not sure what to show really, it just won't build.  Here's my screen when I try to create a new project:[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/WZwL8dz.png)

Comment: All that shows is that the name of your project is "untitled". `erroring out with the Android URI not being found` but you can't show us anything more useful? Like the errors?

Comment: That error is literally in any of my XML files that have the line _xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"_  
I also just noticed that teh SDK and AVD buttons are missing from the top of Android Studio and there are no Android options under my tools menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you do a uninstall of Android Studio and then do a clean install. It might be that there are corrupted or locked system files that are causing the issue. Make sure you backup your Android projects onto a USB first - just in case.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to not have to do that.  Just a lot of stuff to set back up

Comment: I know, but sometimes you can end up losing a day on these things and you never quite figure out why, whereas a clean install just sorts it out. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I was hoping for a quick answer, and since none presented themselves, looks like I'll be starting over.  Thanks though

Answer (score 13):

I recommend you to Reset your Android Studio instead of fresh installation(At least give a try).

**On Windows:**

Go to your User Profile Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

```
 [SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username] (ex. C:\Users\pyus13)
```

Inside this there will be a folder named .AndroidStudioPreview (It can be hidden so please check ).

Delete this folder (Better to take a backup before deletion).

This will reset your AS to defaults.

Now Start your Android Studio you will see the start dialog with settings.

Do the following to set your Android sdk path :

```
 Go into Configure → Project Defaults → Project Structure → Project
```

Add new SDK and referencing to the SDK Folder that you have and then click apply and ok.

Try to open any of your earlier project or create new one and check. try syncing with Gradle after opening project.

**For Linux**

Depending on your AndroidStudio version, the settings are stored in `~/.AndroidStudio, ~/.AndroidStudio1.1 or ~/.AndroidStudio1.2.`

Open a terminal and run the following code:

`ls -a | grep Android` # See which of those three folders above you have. Then rename each of the settings folders you have with the appropriate mv command:

```
mv .AndroidStudio .AndroidStudio.bak
mv .AndroidStudio1.1 .AndroidStudio1.1.bak
mv .AndroidStudio1.2 .AndroidStudio1.2.bak
```

Comment: damn, this solved my problem for which i've spent my 2 days searching for solution! kudos buddy!!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 13):

Go to preference > Plugins uncheck the plugins which appear in red colour and recheck it again.
Do apply
Now the issue will get resolved

Comment: Thanks! That is the best answer!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No reinstall required. Easy and quick fix.

Comment: in my case that was just a lack of Kotlin plugin. AS version is 3.3

Answer (score 2):

Resetting Android Studio worked for me!

You can reset studio by deleting .AndroidStudio directory from Users directory.

```
C:\Users\Abc\\.AndroidStudio
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem for my latest android studio

## Method I ( Unhide the AppData ) :-

1) Show your hidden files from view -> hidden items(check it)
   you will see hidden folders & files as light color.

2) Then go to C:\Users\john     (instead of john, it should be your user name).

3) Right click on "AppData"

4) Just uncheck the Hidden box

5) Move "sdk" folder from C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Android to C:\Users\varad\AppData

6) Open android studio, goto Configure-> Project defaults ->Project structure

7) update new path of SDK like C:\Users\john\AppData\sdk 
   Restart Android Studio.

## Method II ( Move your SDK to another location) :-

1) Move "sdk" folder from C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Android to any folder you want.

2) Then update the SDK path in Android Studio from goto Configure-> Project defaults ->Project structure

3)Restart Android Studio.

:-) Enjoy Android Development.

Answer (score 1):

I go this path:

```
C:\Users\...YOUR-USER-NAME...\.AndroidStudio3.2\config\disabled_plugins.txt
```

remove this line:

```
org.jetbrains.android
```

then refresh SDK in settings. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

This morning I downloaded android studio 2.1, and tried to create new project unfortunately I can't create new project, and I found this post @pyus13 suggests that to reset android studio, but it can't solve this problem.

And I checked android sdk in \AppData\Local\Android\sdk, saw android-23 in platform folder, with my previous experience with eclipse it is ready for running. A couple of hour I found a way to solve this problem, I download android 6.0, api 23 (SDK platform) with android SDK Manager. Do again for creating new project, it is ok.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

**For MAC User**

All plugins, SDK setting was correct still faced the problem.

Applied following solution - on MAC

***Give read write permission to .android folder***

sudo chmod -R 777 .android