# Connection timeout: Can't open new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio v 0.3.2 for the first time in my Windows 7 64 bit OS. When I try to create a new project, I get the following error message:

> Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please
>   configure the proxy settings in Android Either Studio or Gradle.
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Log Show)

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940665/android-studio-cant-create-new-android-project), but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Your solution link is not redirecting to the right webpage.

Comment: Oh Yes , now it is redirectiong to the right link . Thanks

Comment: same problem for me, trying to get it working since last day.

Comment: i have even tried re installing android studio.

Answer (score 0):

It may be proxy issue. You need to set proxy in Android Studio. 
File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Gradle VM Options

For more info, see this link to set proxy in Android Studio : [AndroidStudio gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy)

Comment: I can't even acces to bar menu , i am run it for the first time , i just have acces to an start interface  called "Quick start " can i fix the problem from configure, i can see it in this interface.

Answer (score 0):

The v. 0.3.2 was released a year ago, why don't you install v 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

You Should Allow Android Studio Through Windows Firewall Settings

- i had the same problem all i did was i allowed android studio through my firewall settings and it worked *

1- go to  -> "Control Panel" , then to -> 'System and Security' ,then to -> 'Windows Firewall' 
2- from there choose 'allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall' 
3- choose 'change settings' , then 'allow another app'
4- browse to android studio shortcut and add it , then click ok and that's it !

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem after spending almost 12 hours i figure out that my antivirus was blocking outgoing data from android studio therefore gradle build was not able to finished.

i have just disable firewall in antivirus and it solved the problem in just a minute.