# Android Studio doesn't show options for create android projects

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

There is some problem with my android studio, as it not showing any option to create android apps. Help me out to reset it. I tried to delete it and re-install it but no good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio Can't Create new Android Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940665/android-studio-cant-create-new-android-project)

Answer (score 4):

To reset Android Studio to default settings you need to move or delete its user settings folder.

On Windows you will find it in `C:\Users\Yourname\.AndroidStudio`

You can compress the folder to a zip file or something to back it up and then delete the folder contents.

This will return all of the settings to fresh install default.  This folder remains uneffected by a full re-install so your user settings are kept intact which is the way it should work.

Comment: i am using MAC and i can't find .AndroidStudio

Answer (score 1):

1. Close any open project in Android Studio and it will bring you to Quick Start page.
2. Click Configure and from top, navigate to 'Appearances & Behaviour' > 'System Settings' > 'Android SDK'
3. From the three tabs, choose 'SDK Tools'
4. Select all libraries that are related to Android and install them.
5. Restart Android Studio
6. And volla!