# URI not registered + SDK manager not in toolbar

Tags: android

I'm starting out with Android Studio and everything has been going well thus far. I open Android Studio today and I get a Plugin Error:

"Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.Plugin "Google Cloud Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled."

I searched through SO, and found this question: [Android Studio updates have led to errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681234/android-studio-updates-have-led-to-errors).. but I have no SDK manager in my toolbar nor is there a logo.

In my manifest file and in all my layout files, the line  is underlined red with the error: "URI is not registered (Settings|Project Settings|Schemas and DTDs)

Another thing to add: my design/text pane in all my xml layout files disappeared in today's fiasco as well. While it's not as big of a worry, I'm hoping it maybe gives someone a clue of what's up.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend of mine showed me this link: [Android Studio Can't Create new Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940665/android-studio-cant-create-new-android-project)

Basically, my Windows crashed a few days ago and underwent a disk repair. Something from that repair mode messed with my files, but following the steps from the accepted answer in the link above fixed my issue.

Happy stacking :)